# Does Ant Design Library size effect website performance?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

1. Does Ant Design Library size effect website performance? or adding lot of libraries in react will effect website speed ?

while looking on Ant.Design library size its showing 49MB , means while installing the antd libraries entire components are installing i guess.

2. if am importing only table component from antd does this loads whole library ?
3. Does this library size will effect the website in any ways?
   Is there any possibility to install the needed components separately?

i have found a section in antd documentation , its showing below
[image]
what does its means? only the components we imported only gets bundles in the build?

4. Finlay one more question if i installed a library and not used it in the code does this library will be get bundled in the build?

Comment: It's a yes for your first question. Only because Ant library support tree shaking. 
Check this webpack docs for more details on tree shaking. https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/

Answer (score 2):

1. First question, Huge library size it will affect website performance, but `tree-shaking` can solve this problem. And `Ant Design` support `tree-shaking`.
2. If you import only table component from antd, it will not load the whole library
3. Yes, because if the website is too large, it will take a long time for users to load. You can use `tree-shaking` solve this problem.
4. `import { Button } from 'antd';`
   It is only install `Button` Component code to your bundled, not all `antd` component.

[Tree Shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/),
[Code Splitting](https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/) There are two good solutions when it comes to website size problem.

Comment: i have doubt in 2nd and 4th answer, hmmm... is this 2 answer for if i use tree- shaking? or not using tree shaking is this both anser 2 and 4 feasible?

Comment: you need to use tree shaking, so it only loads your imported component rather than all components

Comment: I think this is not about Ant Design, is about the bundle tools